# Why must every vector in V belongs to one of the generalised eigenspaces of $T: V \to V?$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Why must every vector in V belongs to one of the generalised eigenspaces of $T: V \to V?$ Is there a simple proof for this? Can someone provide me with an intuition behind it?

Note that V is an algebraically closed field.

Comment: It is not true that every vector in $V$ belongs to a generalized eigenspace.

Comment: The question definitely needs to be restated.  And these things should be defined—this is definitely false if $V$ is infinite-dimensional, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that all the eigenvalues of $T$ are in the field of scalars of $V$ ( true if $k=\mathbb{C}$. Then $V$ is a direct sum of the generalized eigenspaces $V_{\lambda}$. That is, every vector can be written uniquely as 
$$v = \sum_{\lambda} v_{\lambda}$$

where $(T-\lambda)^{n_{\lambda}}v_{\lambda} = 0$. Note that any vector for which more than one component $v_{\lambda}$ is nonzero cannot belong to any $V_{\mu}$.

A very simple example is $T= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 &0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array} \right)$. Consider $v = e_1 + e_2 = (1,0)+(0,1) = (1,1)$.

Comment: why is V a direct sum of the generalized eigenspaces?

Comment: @user136266: One way to see it is through Jordan block decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes down to understanding the characteristic polynomial.

Suppose that $PQ = 0$, where $P$ and $Q$ are relatively prime polynomials of $T$.  Then $V = PV \oplus QV$.  This is basically the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but we can see it directly: if $AP + BQ = 1$, then $v = APv+BPv$, and if $w \in PV \cap QV$, then $Pw = Qw = 0$, so $w = (AP+BQ)w = 0$.

Note that $P$ is invertible on $PV$, and $Q$ is invertible on $QV$.

So, if we completely factor the characteristic polynomial, we can decompose $V$ into summands $V_\lambda$ corresponding to the eigenvalues.  Furthermore, each $V_\lambda$ has only $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue, because each $T-\tau$ is invertible on $V_\lambda$ when $\lambda \neq \tau$.

My claim is that $V_\lambda$ is exactly the generalized eigenspace, and we can go home happy.

One standard definition is that the generalized eigenspace of $\lambda$ is the set of vectors $v$ which lie in the kernel of some power of $T-\lambda$.  Clearly any such vector lies in $V_\lambda$, because, again, $T-\lambda$ is invertible on the other factors.  So we just need to show that every vector in $V_\lambda$ has this property.

But this is straightforward: on $V_\lambda$, the only eigenvalue of $T$ is $\lambda$.  There are many ways to see, from this fact, that $T-\lambda$ is nilpotent, but one way is to look at its characteristic polynomial.  Another is to notice that each successive application must lower the dimension.